# Unity Animation Rigging PoleTarget?

Tags: unity, rigging

I'm working on procedural animation for a robot-walking character in Unity. Currently, I'm using a Chain IK constraint for movement of the leg because the leg has three joints. I set the position of each foot with a Raycast, Lerp, and Sin wave as they do in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acMK93A-FSY).  However, the walking animation barely moves the first joints at all and it feels like the last joint is moved an inordinate amount. It makes the walking look strange.

I would like an effect similar to the "pole target" that I used when modeling and rigging this character in blender, or some equivalent that would provide these legs with a better looking range of motion.

A gif demonstrating the problem in unity
https://i.imgur.com/PmGhWxb.gifv 
A gif demonstrating how it looked in blender https://i.imgur.com/hY2YAoC.gifv

Comment: Can you show us a video/gif of your implementation? Have you tried tweaking the "weights" of the IK in the tutorial you're following.

Comment: What are you looking to see exactly? I can't see any "weights" on individual bones. Thank you!